# Operations with matrices inside a loop in Python

Tags: python, matrix

I have two matrices, A and B.

```
A=np.matrix([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])
B=np.matrix([[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3],[4,4,4]])
```

I want to substract some of B'rows (namely 0,2 and 3) from A. I tried to use

```
Index=np.array([0,2,3]) 
for i in Index:
   A[i,:]=A[i,:]-B[i,:]
```

but it didn't work because matriz A should look like

```
matrix([[0, 1, 2],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [6, 7, 8]])
```

and I got

```
matrix([[ 1,  2,  3],
    [ 2,  3,  4],
    [ 7,  8,  9],
    [10, 11, 12]])
```

What's the correct way to do this operation? I took me a long time to realize this problem (the real problem I'm trying to solve has more variables) and can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

If you do mean **substract**, then your should use

```
A[i,:]=A[i,:]-B[i,:]
```

instead of

```
A[i,:]=A[i,:]+B[i,:]
```

Comment: Yes, I mean to use the minus sign. The problem still persists, obviously, because Python is not making the operations componentwise

Comment: There are something wrong with your expected output or the `Index=np.array([0,2,3])`. There seems no way to get the expected output from the given `Index`. @Fawcett512

Answer (score 1):

Numpy has element-wise subtraction, so something like:

```
import numpy as np

A=np.matrix([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])
B=np.matrix([[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3],[4,4,4]])

indices = [0,2,3]
for i in indices:
    A[i,:]=np.subtract(A[i,:], B[i,:])
```

Will give you this matrix for A:

```
[[0, 1, 2],
 [4, 5, 6],
 [4, 5, 6],
 [6, 7, 8]])
```

Is this what you are after? For better performance you could also just change the particular rows of A:

```
A[indices]=np.subtract(A[indices],B[indices])
```

Which will give the same answer.